# Error al guardar un input text

Tags: html, mysql, post

Al guardar un input-text en una base Mysql, no me deja. Al tocar en submit me tira el siguiente error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputemail' of undefined
>       at routes.post (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\server\routes\routes.js:11:31)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Este es mi código HTML:

```
<div id="screen">
            <form action="/contact" method="post">
                <h5>Email</h5>
                <input type="text" id="inputemail" name="inputemail" >
                <h5>Comentario</h5>
                <textarea id="areacoment" name="areacoment"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Enviar</button>
            </form>
       </div>
```

Este mi routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = express.Router();
const pool= require("../mysql/mysql");
const mysql=require("../mysql/mysql");


routes.post("/contact",(req,res)=>{
    var inputemail = req.body.inputemail;
    pool.query("INSERT INTO contact (email, info) VALUES (?, ?)", [inputemail, inputcoment],
        function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) { throw error }
            if (results) { console.log(results); }
        }
    );
    res.render("index.html");
});

module.exports=routes;
```

Este es mi index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const routes = express.Router();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = require("express-myconnection");

//SETTINGS
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080);
//ROUTES
app.use(require("./routes/routes"));
//STATIC FILES
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
//MYSQL
app.use(connection(mysql,{
host:"localhost",
user: "pedri",
password:"cocoypaco2",
database:"vegi",
port:3306
},"single"));

//LISTEN SERVER
app.listen(app.get("port"),()=>{
console.log("Server on port ", app.get("port"));
});
```

Comment: Estás utilizando `body-parser` o alguna forma de leer los datos de `req.body`, sería bueno que compartas tu `index.js` o el archivo donde corre tu app de express.

Comment: Ahí lo compartí Martiuh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta poner un `middleware` para manipular la post data, `express` por sí mismo no lo hace. Por eso puedes utilizar algun módulo como `formidable` o `multer` que leen el formato `multipart/form-data`

simplemente necesitas

```
$ npm install formidable --save
## o yarn add formidable
```

y en tu `routes.js` agregas lo siguiente

```
// routes.js
// todas tus dependencias aquí
const formidable= require("formidable");

routes.post("/contact",(req,res)=>{
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

   form.parse(req, (err, formFields, formFiles) => {
     const { inputemail, inputcoment } = formFields
    pool.query("INSERT INTO contact (email, info) VALUES (?, ?)", [inputemail, inputcoment],
        function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) { throw error }
            if (results) { console.log(results); }
        }
    );
    /* 
      si esperas mandar index.html
      en base al resultado de la `query`
      los tienes que mandar dentro de la
      `callback` de `pool.query`
    */
    res.render("index.html");
    });
});
```

#### Editado

También existe un error con tu form estás declarando

```
<textarea id="areacoment" name="areacoment" />
```

Por esa razón la query no se ejecuta correctamente pues `inputcoment` no está definida en ningún lugar de la tabla, entonces si quieres utilizar el `name="inputcoment"` tienes que modificar tu `<textarea>` para que quede así

```
<textarea id="inputcoment" name="inputcoment"></textarea>
```

y de esa forma ya podrás leer la variable.

Un último comentario es que la forma correcta de escribirlo sería `inputcomment`

Comment: Martiuh me tiras este error :/

Comment: Martiuh me tira este error :/   Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'info' cannot be null
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Piter\Desktop\Goven\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)

Comment: Hola Pedro, sí ya vi el error y agregué la solución a mi respuesta. espero que ya puedas leer la información que necesitas y crear una aplicación genial.

Comment: Martiuh!!!!! Me sirvió, muchísimas gracias me sacaste un gran muro de adelante. Estoy haciendo una pagina que promueve el veganismo y quiero mostrar los productos de mi país que lo son, por que lo son o por que no y muchas otras cosas y esto era fundamental. Muchísimas gracias de verdad, sos un genio!

Comment: Me da gusto que te haya funcionado, espero que te quede genial el sitio. Y si mi respuesta fue la que te sirvió, marcarlo como solucionado el problema? Saludos

Comment: Martiuh, disculpa que te moleste a estas alturas, quizá ni te llegue la notificación de esto, no se moverme muy bien por aca jajaja. El problema es que ahora necesito mostrar unos datos en pantalla. Ya hice el la coneccion con el route y todo como "tendria que ser" pero el problema es que no se donde ni que poner que represente el valor que quiero mostrar. Si un dia tenes un tiempito de sobra me avisas y me decis que te tengo que mostrar y te voy enseñando. Gracias y perdon!

Comment: Hola Pedro que tal, para empezar no me queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Necesito más información y me puedes mandar tu duda por telegram mi usuario es el mismo que aquí.